# best way to transform the column element and create new row items

Tags: pandas

I have to transform the below pandas dataframe as shown  below. The column X7 has some elements which needs to be split and formed into new rows

```
X1  Y   X7
117 AA  "1256 (LM)
        1257 (LM)
         1258 (LM)"
118 LL   131 (NB)
         132 (NB)
         133 (NB)
```

to the below dataframe

```
X1  Y   X7
117 AA  1256(LM)
117 AA  1257(LM)
117 AA  1258(LM)
118 LL  131(NB)
118 LL  132(NB)
118 LL  133(NB)
```

Comment: I don't see any image, better to use a code block in any case.

Comment: X1     Y              X7

117     AA           1256 (LM)
                           1257 (LM)
                            1258 (LM)
118      LL             132 (FF)

Comment: Can you add data sample to question as text with desired output? 3-4 rows is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#set index to all columns for repeat
#split column X7 by separator
#reshape by stack
#convert MultiIndex to columns
df = (df.set_index(['X1','Y'])['X7']
        .str.split('\n', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='X7')
        .drop('level_2', axis=1)
        )
print (df)
    X1   Y         X7
0  117  AA  1256 (LM)
1  117  AA  1257 (LM)
2  117  AA  1258 (LM)
3  118  LL   131 (NB)
4  118  LL   132 (NB)
5  118  LL   133 (NB)
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is exactly what I needed